# use Python .format(urlencode) in a for Loop

Tags: python-3.x, urlencode, urlopen

I have a dict with some Id's as a value list. For this list I want to use a loop to insert each ids and the key in the URL using .format.

The goal is that the URL looks like this:

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen('https://lignumdata.ch/api/v1.cfc?method=getBauteil&type=all&condition={"**KEY**":"**ITEM FROM LOOP**"}').read()
```

How do I have to proceed?

my code:

```
myDict = {'={"id":'['1838A0BD-EFED-AC5F-110BFF3266C2A08C', '1838C66B-0E3C-0073-A52F55BFEF1CDDD7', '1838D369-FE2D-54FD-993706CE152D2A1D', '18398B8C-0B6B-33A6-92BAA6FB216995F9', '18399F2E-BCA9-0457-C28BAFA5F7466181', '1839AD62-B125-1D7C-E4FD205840A3B7B4', '183A43AD-9D1C-8121-D3FA5FB69C2BE2CF', '183A53B2-CBB5-13B3-29B77034EABCE1C8', '183A61F0-CD79-878B-EA9943B8C9EA12D0', '183A692D-ED62-DA89-057A2630F061B29F', '183AC5C6-BF39-0359-12C6FBB14392EAFC', '183AD460-9F06-3841-E660630702C40991']}
```

Result should look like this:

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen('https://lignumdata.ch/api/v1.cfc?method=getBauteil&type=all&condition={"id":"192E4CD9-B41B-09E3-1C2148F313A3A83B"}').read()
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: could you please make more clear your input and output.
Try to look into f string where you could fave `f'text{do something here}'`
Or prepare string before and format it later

Comment: adding on - do you have one URL that you want to add multiple login ids to or multiple URLs to manipulate?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In python3 You can use `f' '` syntax to format a string. Combination of that with a Lambda function can define you formatting template.

Also to iterate over keys of a dictionary you can use `dict.keys` function.

```
d = {"id": ["1", "2", "3"]}
url = lambda k,v : f'https://lignumdata.ch/api/v1.cfc?method=getBauteil&type=all&condition={{"{k}":"{v}"}}'

for k in dict.keys(d):
    for v in d[k]:
        print(url(k,v))
```